# How to write to a Realm object server on Ubuntu

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have worked through the Realm mobile platform tutorial ([link](https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/example-app/cocoa/)). You create a Swift task app.

I was able to get the app and server working correctly on my local mac. I was able to add tasks to the tableview.

I then created an Ubuntu 16.04 droplet on DigitalOcean. I managed to get the server running and am able to view the Realm dashboard.

The problem is that when I run the app with the new server ip address (the ubuntu instance), I see the 'Add task' pop up but no tasks get added to the tableview on the app.

The following code adds tasks to the db:

```
try! items.realm?.write {
 items.insert(Task(value: ["text": text]), at: items.filter("completed = false").count)
}
```

When I run the code on my local machine it inserts values but the `insert` line is never hit when I use the remote server.

Here is where I set the Realm config to the new url:

```
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
                syncConfiguration: (user, URL(string: "realm://128.199.119.xxx:9080/~/realmtasks")!)
        )
```

Do you have to update the Realm `configuration.yml` file when you deploy it to a remote server? If yes, does anyone have a `configuration.yml` example or what needs to be done to get the file setup?

In the tutorial video it is mentioned that the info.plist needs to be updated. Will the below edition to the info.plist be the same for an app accessing a deployed server or an app on the app store?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Here is the result of `cat /var/log/realm-object-server.log`:

```
2016-10-29T03:09:06.501Z - info: sync-server: Connection[5]: Connection from 127.0.0.1:58822
2016-10-29T03:09:06.631Z - info: sync-server: Connection[5]: Received: CLIENT(protocol_version=15, client_info_size=2, client_info='{}')
2016-10-29T03:09:06.788Z - info: sync-server: Connection[5]: Session[1]: Session initiated (session_ident=1).
2016-10-29T03:09:06.789Z - info: sync-server: Connection[5]: Session[1]: Received: BIND(server_path=/72c5a/realmtasks, signed_user_token='...xxm/7UjDkuEqQ==', need_file_ident_pair=0)
2016-10-29T03:09:06.789Z - info: sync-server: Connection[5]: Session[1]: Received: IDENT(server_file_ident=21314, client_file_ident=1, client_file_ident_secret=1477, scan_server_version=2, scan_client_version=2, latest_server_version=2, latest_server_session_ident=1643)
2016-10-29T03:09:17.069Z - info: sync-server: Connection[5]: Session[1]: Session terminated (session_ident=1).
2016-10-29T03:09:17.070Z - info: sync-server: Connection[5]: Connection closed by client: End of input
2016-10-29T03:09:26.769Z - info: sync-server: Connection[6]: Connection from 127.0.0.1:58866
2016-10-29T03:09:26.895Z - info: sync-server: Connection[6]: Received: CLIENT(protocol_version=15, client_info_size=2, client_info='{}')
2016-10-29T03:09:27.053Z - info: sync-server: Connection[6]: Session[1]: Session initiated (session_ident=1).
2016-10-29T03:09:27.053Z - info: sync-server: Connection[6]: Session[1]: Received: BIND(server_path=/a4fdec5a/realmtasks, signed_user_token='...K0k7mw==', need_file_ident_pair=0)
2016-10-29T03:09:27.053Z - info: sync-server: Connection[6]: Session[1]: Received: IDENT(server_file_ident=21094, client_file_ident=1, client_file_ident_secret=14907, scan_server_version=2, scan_client_version=2, latest_server_version=2, latest_server_session_ident=164553)
```

The object server is running and I can see the task and taskList tables but I cannot write records to the table.

When I check `auth.log` I get the following

```
Nov  1 10:53:22 digitalocean sshd[13684]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.229.172.111  user=root
Nov  1 10:53:49 digitalocean sshd[13701]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.229.172.111  user=root
Nov  1 10:53:50 digitalocean sshd[13701]: Failed password for root from 221.229.172.111 port 43992 ssh2
Nov  1 10:53:55 digitalocean sshd[13701]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 221.229.172.111 port 43992 ssh2]
Nov  1 10:53:55 digitalocean sshd[13701]: Received disconnect from 221.229.172.111 port 43992:11:  [preauth]
Nov  1 10:53:55 digitalocean sshd[13701]: Disconnected from 221.229.172.111 port 43992 [preauth]
Nov  1 10:53:55 digitalocean sshd[13701]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.229.172.111  user=root
```

Comment: I deployed ROS to a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 16.04) with out any issues and my deployment is running fine.  Have you considered destroying the droplet and starting over?  Maybe a step in the deployment was missed or done out of sequence - you just might find it easier to start over.

Comment: The first droplet I included firewall and restricted access to ssh only. I destroyed the droplet and started again without those and still had an issue. I have no idea what else to look for.

Comment: Damn.  I literally created a new droplet, created a new system user and gave that user SUDO privileges, followed the Realm Linux install instructions.  That was it.  It just worked.  I figured I'll deal with firewalls and ssl etc at a later date.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Will try with another new droplet.

Comment: @IanBradbury were you working through the Realm mobile platform task example / tutorial? Did you manage to get it to work with the Ubuntu server?

Comment: Yes - I got the example working first time.  I didn't have any issues.

Comment: Just a few things: the `auth.log` is your system authentication log. It has nothing to do with Realm. From your Realm log, we can see that there were connections with successful `BIND`s, so it would appear "everything worked".

Comment: Thanks @teotwaki. Do you know why the try! items.realm?.write is writing to the db on my local machine but not when I try write to the ubuntu server (that you've shown me is connected correctly)?

Comment: There is no concept of "writing to the server" in Realm. You always work on a local database, which can then be subsequently synchronised to the server if connected. I'm not sure why that try would block.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the probem.

In the tutorial's `updateList()` function:

```
func updateList() {
 if self.items.realm == nil, let list = self.realm.objects(TaskList.self).first {
  self.items = list.items
 }
 self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

`self.items` will never get set because `self.realm.objects(TaskList.self).first` will return nil until there is a task added to the list. You need to add a task (in my case using the Mac version of the app) before the iOS version of the code will work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You need to launch RealmTasks for macOS or iOS before you can display and created other tasks.
> "If you build and run the app now, it should connect to the object server and display the tasks that were added in RealmTasks earlier."